# MonoGame - Android SamplerState.LinearWrap

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android, monogame

We use `SamplerState.LinearWrap` to tile alot of things in our game.  Our game shares a single `SpriteBatch` object, and calls `Begin()` like this:

```
_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.None, _rasterState);
```

This works great for XNA on Windows as well as MonoGame on iOS.

Problem is, on Android, if LinearWrap is turned on, any non-power of two sized texture render as a black rectangle, even if it is drawn in a way where it would not need to be wrapped.  If we switch to `SamplerState.LinearClamp` (the default), these textures no longer render black on Android.  Normally non-power of two textures leave empty space up to the next largest power of two if you try to tile them (on other platforms).

Is this a limitation of OpenGL on Android, or is an issue in MonoGame?  I would hate to resize every texture to be a power of two, but we would do it if it is the only option (or there is a very good reason to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through MonoGame, I found this in ESTexture2D.cs:

```
                _width = imageSource.Width;
                _height = imageSource.Height;

                // There are rules for npot textures that we must abide by (wrap = ClampToEdge and filter = Nearest or Linear)
                if (!MathHelper.IsPowerOfTwo(_width) || !MathHelper.IsPowerOfTwo(_height))
                {
                    //filter = ALL11.Linear;
                    //wrap = ALL11.ClampToEdge;
                    _width = (int)Math.Pow(2, Math.Min(10, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(imageSource.Width) / Math.Log10(2))));
                    _height = (int)Math.Pow(2, Math.Min(10, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(imageSource.Height) / Math.Log10(2))));
                }
```

I commented out the changes to `filter` and `wrap`, and adjusted the size to be a power of two.

This resolved my issue, but I'm not sure if is a valid fix for MonoGame.  I don't know what effect it would have if you were using `SamplerState.LinearClamp`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been fixed in the develop3d branch.

D.

Comment: Thanks, Dominique, we are going to start making the switch to develop3d soon.